# Orbiting object around orbiting object

Tags: c++, opengl, math, rotation, coordinates

[image]

How do I get to orbit **green** circle **around orange** and **blue around green** ?

I found many solutions which works fine with rotating around static point(int this case orange circle) but didn't find any good maths equation which would work for both static and moving points.

```
angle += sunRot;

if(angle > 360.0f)
{
    angle = 0.0f;
}

float radian = glm::radians(angle);

float radius = glm::distance(position, rotCenter);

float x = rotCenter.x + (radius * cosf(radian));
float z = rotCenter.z + (radius * sinf(radian));

glm::vec3 newPos = glm::vec3(x, 0, z);

setPosition(newPos);
```

[Here is](http://hascanvas.com/coordinates) what I'm trying to achieve  (Thanks to @George Profenza for sharing link)

Comment: All you need to do is transform each of the objects in the correct order. You would first rotate the green object around the orange object to get its location. Then you use the location of the green object and rotate the blue object around it. They have perfect circular orbits, so you can translate them a fixed distance from the center of the object they orbit.

Comment: Do you need something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVuU2YCwHjw&feature=youtu.be&t=1m)?

Comment: @peter-wood , no, I just try to simulate earth rotating around sun and moon rotating around earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base all your calculations on the radius and angle of the current object where possible and store the radius and angle with the object.

In particular, do not calculate the radius based on the x/y coordinates in every iteration: If the base object has moved between steps, your calculated radius will be slightly off and the error will accumulate.

Comment: And that was the issue :) Fixed now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to nest coordinate spaces using opengl using `glPushMatrix()`, `glPopMatrix()` calls. [Here](http://hascanvas.com/coordinates)'s a basic example(press mouse to see coordinate spaces). 
The syntax isn't c++, but it's easy to see what I mean.

You can do this multiple ways:

1. polar coordinate formula
2. manually multiplying transformation matrices
3. simply using push/pop matrix calls (along with translate/rotate where needed), which does the matrix multiplication for you behind the scenes.

Just in case you want to try the polar coordinate formula:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius
y = sin(angle) * radius
```

Where angle is the current rotation of a circle and the radius is it's distance from the centre of rotation.

Comment: That is what I've been doing (polar coordinate formula) it works, only for orbiting around sun, but the moon orbit increases with every iteration. Check my code in the answer (I just added).